# Error in i + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

Trying to print out all these letters but I keep getting an error at i <- i + 1, any idea how to fix?

```
y <- c("q","w","e","r","z","c")
print(y)
for(i in y)
{
 print(y[i])
 i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: You're looping through the elements of `y`, not the indices, so just use `print(i)` inside the loop. Also, you don't need to adjust the index even if you were looping through the indices, that is useful if using a `while` loop, such as `while (i <= length(y))`.

Comment: The for-loop is incrementing the loop variable. Why you need `i <- i+1`